# Why add.df was not created in R?

Tags: r, object

I am having error: Warning message:
In rm(df, Add.df, files, z) : object 'Add.df' not found

`Add.df <- as.data.frame(cbind("ID" = (nrow(Final.df)+1):(nrow(df)+nrow(Final.df))`
`"Created" = df$created,`
 `"Expires" = df$expires,`
`"Company" = df$company,`
 `"ERVK.name" = df$EVRK_text,`
`"ERVK.code" = df$EVRK,`
`"Position" = df$position,`
`"Requirments" = df$requirements,`
 `"Description" = df$description,`
 `"Required.Education" = NA,`
`"Adress" = df$`Darbo vietos adresas`,`
`"LPK.6.code" = NA,`
`"LPK.4.code" = NA,`
`"LPK.6.name" = NA,`
  `"LPK.4.name" = NA,`
 `"Position.clean" = df$Ad.clean,`
 `"Company.clean" = df$Company.clean,`
`"City.clean" = df$City.clean,`
`"Website" = unlist(strsplit(files[z],"_"))[1]),`
`stringsAsFactors = FALSE)`
`Final.df <- rbind(Final.df, Add.df)`

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a typo in `"Adress" = df$Darbo vietos adresas,`

Comment: It was written like df$' Darbo vietos adresas '

Comment: There is no way for anyone to properly troubleshoot this because you are not providing a reproducible example or your data. The only thing I would suggest is that, as a novice user, it is best you avoid using colnames with spaces or special character. So, rename `Darbo vietos adresas ` to `Darbo_vietos_adresas`.

Comment: I have changed to yours case but the  same warning appears

Comment: Whats more could be wrong in that dataframe, Add.df?

Comment: I got two more errors in same dataframe. Errors are these: Error in (nrow(Final.df) + 1):(nrow(df) + nrow(Final.df)) : 
  argument of length 0, Error in rbind(deparse.level, ...) : object 'Add.df' not found

Comment: you are not creating add.df because of an error and then you are trying to rbind the not created object to final.df.  You have `df` and `files` objects already and as I said above we cannot really help unless the data is understood. Perhaps before creating  `add.df` you should explain what you are trying to accomplish. Also, have a look at the function `rbind.fill` because it seems you are trying to bind frames with different columns.

Comment: In add.df I am trying to cbind new column within existing final.df data.

Comment: How solve this error: Error in (nrow(Final.df) + 1):(nrow(df) + nrow(Final.df)) : 
  argument of length 0?

Comment: How to convert character to Date this 20180108?as.Date() function not worked for df

Comment: How I could solve this - Error in if (length(match) > 0 & nchar(Final.df$Company.clean[i]) > 5) { : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Comment: How I could solve this Error in (nrow(Final.df) + 1):(nrow(df) + nrow(Final.df)) : 
  argument of length 0? That I am getting when executing Add.df object creation.

Comment: I found that nrow(df) is NULL but why because df was created with many records.

Comment: When I run that code until end I am getting this error: Error in (nrow(Final.df) + 1):(nrow(df) + nrow(Final.df)) : 
  argument of length 0